# Using Newtonsoft (Json.NET) to serialize System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry collection

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, serialization, json.net

I'm trying to gather windows events that satisfy a particular query and serialize them to JSON so that I can import that collection into a MongoDB database.  This is just me practicing and fooling around, but I got stuck at this point and would love to be able to move forward.

## The problem:

When I use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(...)`, I certainly do get it to serialize something similar to the object in the sense that there are a few properties that survived:

```
public class EventSerializer
{
    public static void Serialize(EventLogEntry eventLogEntry)
    {
        var traceWriter = new MemoryTraceWriter();
        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eventLogEntry, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TraceWriter = traceWriter
        });
        Console.WriteLine(traceWriter);
    }
}
```

#### Output:

```
{
    "DataBuffer": "<seemingly-random, long string>",
    "LogName": "Application",
    "MachineName": "<my machine's name>"
}
```

I can even deserialize the object and get what I expected back.  But I really don't want the DataBuffer key-value pair in there, I want the contents of the `EventLogEntry` to be readable to so that I can parse that information out of MongoDB.

I've been looking through the documentation for `Json.NET`, and I'm wondering if I need to do something with creating my own `Converter` or something, but I'm having a little trouble understanding it all from here.  There is also talk, [in the documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#Objects), of the ability to opt-in/opt-out of serializing particular properties/fields, but it isn't clear to me how one would do that to an object whose declaration/specification wasn't written by one's self.

Any and all help/suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot deserialize JSON into a new `EventLogEntry` object. One reason is that some the properties in `EventLogEntry` are read-only properties, and the getters for theses properties contain logic to calculate the values, i.e., they are not a simple getters that obtain the value from internally stored field.

I suggest that you create a special object to hold the data. Here is an example:

```
public class MyEventLogEntry
{
    public string MachineName { get; set; }
    public DateTime GeneratedTime { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public long InstanceId { get; set; } 
}
```

You can put in this class the event properties that you are interested in. They can even have different names than the ones inside `EventLogEntry`.

You can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to easily convert from `EventLogEntry` to `MyEventLogEntry`. Or you can do it manually if you want.

Here is a code sample that uses AutoMapper:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<EventLogEntry, MyEventLogEntry>()
    .ForMember(dst => dst.InstanceId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.InstanceId))
    .ForMember(dst => dst.Message, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Message))
    .ForMember(dst => dst.GeneratedTime, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TimeGenerated))
    .ForMember(dst => dst.MachineName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.MachineName));

EventLog log = new EventLog("Application");

EventLogEntry entry = log.Entries[0];

MyEventLogEntry my_entry = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<EventLogEntry, MyEventLogEntry>(entry);

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(my_entry);

MyEventLogEntry deserialized_entry = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyEventLogEntry>(json);
```

Please note that the call to `AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap` needs to done only once (e.g. at the start of your application).

You can use `MyEventLogEntry` when you want to read/write from/to the database.

Comment: thank you very much for your help!  If you would, could you elaborate on why read-only properties prevent serialization like this from happening?  Or is it that the getters are calculating rather than just returning a private member?  I would really like to understand this better.  Also, AutoMapper was pretty neat to work with.  Thanks again.

Comment: The easiest way for a deserializer to deserialize objects is to invoke the property setters, and read-only properties do not have property setters. Regarding private fields, if read-only property has a backing field, you could theoretically do some magic using [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx) and change the value of such private field.